# How to get a trello card based on position

Tags: javascript, trello

I’m trying to get the top Trello card in a specific list, but I’m unsure how to get a card from a list based on its position. Any ideas? Also, I’m pretty knowledgeable with the Trello API already I just can’t figure this out at all.

So far I have this, but I don’t know how to get the top card.

```js
let listID = "5ec3fda8a26c384e44f063bb";

trello.getCardsOnListWithExtraParams(listID, "pos:top",
  function(error, trelloCard) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('An error occured with Trello card.' + error)
      message.channel.send({
        embed: {
          color: 0xff604d,
          description: "An error occured! Please try again later or use the support server link."
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log('Found card:', trelloCard);
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when I use your code and add [0] to the trelloCard that it logs, it works fine and gets the first one in the list.

```
trello.getCardsOnListWithExtraParams(listID, "pos:top",
      function (error, trelloCard) {
          if (error) {
              console.log('An error occured with Trello card.' + error)
           //testing this in console so I removed the message.channel.send
          }
          else {
              console.log('Found card:', trelloCard[0]);
          }
        })
```

Outputs:

```
...
name: 'two',
pos: 0.5,
...
```

which is first

[image: trello screenshot]